# Yii- Ajax value not getting fired into controller

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm new to Yii framework and Ajax. So now I'm using a **`ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox`** for creating a dropdownlist. Below is the code I'm using to create the dropdownlist in the view file :

```
<?php
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'company_id',
    // data to populate the select. Must be an array.
    //'data' => $model->getAllModels(),
    'data' => CHtml::listData(Company::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
    // options passed to plugin
    // Options passed to the text input
    'options' => array(
        // JS code to execute on 'select' event, the selected item is
        // available through the 'item' variable.
        'onSelect' => CHtml::ajax(array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createAbsoluteUrl('bill/getProjects'),
                'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'project_id'),
                                'beforeSend' => 'function(){
                                    $("#page").addClass("loading");}',
                                'complete' => 'function(){
                                    $("#page").removeClass("loading");
                                    $("#' . CHtml::activeId($model,'project_id') . '").trigger("change");
                                }',
                               'success'=>"function(){
                alert('ok');}"

            )),
        // JS code to be executed on 'change' event, the input is available
        // through the '$(this)' variable.

        'allowText' => false,
    ),
    // Options passed to the text input
    'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:70px'
            )
)); ?>
```

Now, the ajax gets fired to controller, but the value of project_id is still 0. Now in the controller I have the following function. The alert box gets executed.

```
public function actionGetProjects()
    {
        $data=Project::model()->findAll('company_id=:company_id',
            array(':company_id'=>(int) $_POST['Bill']['company_id']));

        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
        foreach($data as $value=>$name)
        {
            echo CHtml::tag('option',
                array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
        }
    }
```

In the logs generated I can see though I selected the company_id from values, the comapny_id says the value is 0. How can I debug this?

```
SELECT * FROM `project` `t` WHERE company_id=0
```

**Edit**
Below is the look of view page
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can go around this issue with setting the name for html options

```
'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:70px' , 'name' => 'Bill[company_id]' ),
```

UPDATE : I'm using this setting for widget

```
     $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
            'id' => 'agentAuto',
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'id',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('name'=>'Calendar[name]'),
            'options' => array(
                'item' => array(
                    'label' => 'name',
                    'value' => 'id'
                ),
                'path' => 'CallBackData.User',
                'afterChange'=>'fillDropdowns(el.element)',
                'url' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/user/AutoList?limit=10'
            )
        ));
```

Comment: I don't see the value printed anywhere. I get the values in dropdown I selected company1, but the id of comapny1 is not sent to controller

Comment: I tried this, but still the query executed is the same `SELECT * FROM project t WHERE company_id=0  `I don't know why the company_id=0 evenif I'm selecting a value

Comment: inspect the html with firebug to see better whats happening

Comment: No luck...I want to know why the value passed is 0 to controller